# geany 1.32 - change color of bracket matching

Tags: geany

In this version the highlight for matching brackets is dark blue which against a black foreground font is not a significant highlight. Ubuntu 18.04 MATE.

How can I set this to a brighter color?

Web query results haven't much for geany on this topic. The solution given here https://lists.geany.org/pipermail/users/2015-December/009843.html does not work for me. The `filetypes-common` file does not have a `[named-styles]` section so I added one.

This has no effect. Is there an updated solution, or is there something else amiss?

Comment: Copied to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110685/geany-1-32-change-color-of-bracket-matching-18-10-mate

Answer (score 0):

A good solution from DK Bose at askubuntu -- using geany's color scheme feature:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110685/geany-1-32-change-color-of-bracket-matching-18-10-mate/1110709#1110709

Many schemes offer the same general look of the default scheme with slightly different colorings. The scheme configuration files are plain text property files so it is easy to create custom schemes.

The properties for matching brackets are `brace_good` and `brace_bad`.

It looks like Geany rewrites its config on exit to ~/.config/geany/geany.conf so for scheme selection change to persist you must make the selection in the last instance standing.